# Get the id of inserted document in Mongo database in expressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I use ExpressJS to insert documents in MongoDB. I want to get the last inserted object id

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {

    console.log(res.id); //this line doesn't work
    console.log(res); //this line prints all the results
    res.redirect('/');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `res._id` or if you used `insertOne()` or `insertMany()` functions to create the record, try `res.insertedId`.

More info in MongoDB documentation: [insert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) [insertOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/) [insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `callback` function to get the `_id` once the `document` is inserted.

Change you `id` to

> _id

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {

    console.log(res._id); 
    console.log(res); //this line prints all the results
    res.redirect('/');

});
```